# Find The Locus of the Triangle When the Difference of Its Base Angles are Given

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, analytic-geometry, problem-solving, coordinate-systems

This problem is found in S.L. Loney's book on The Elements of Coordinate Geometry. The problem is pronounced in full as follows:

*The base BC (=2a) of a triangle ABC is fixed; the axes being BC and a perpendicular to it through its middle point, find the locus of the vertex A, when the difference of the base angles is given (=a)*

The way I attempted at it was: I realised that once the tangent of one of the angles was $=$$y\over x + a$ then the other would be equal to $=$$y\over x — a$. Hence let the tangent of one of the base angles, B (say), be $y\over x + a$; and let the tangent of C then be $y\over x — a$. And it is given that $B — C = a$. Taking the tangent of both sides of the last equation, we get: $\tan (B — C) =$$\tan B — \tan C \over 1 + \tan B \tan C$. Since we know the values of all these expressions we can substitute to get:

$\tan a =$$—2ay \over x^2 + y^2 — a^2$

Algebraically rearranging this equation we get

$x^2\tan a + y^2\tan a + 2ay — a^2\tan a = 0$

or much more concisely:

$\tan a(x^2 + y^2 — a^2) + 2ay = 0$

I am still knew to the grand picture of Coordinate Geometry, hence I seek affirmation from the more profesional of the answer I have provided to satisfy the problem. If I have made any fallacy in reasoning, reader, please say so and show me how its properly done. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `$\tan a$` for $\tan a$.

Comment: I fail to see what you mean. MathJax isn't recognising $\tana$. Also, could you perhaps also tell me if my solution of the problem is acceptable?

Comment: That's because you missed out the space between `n` and `a`.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with this question. Geometry is not my forte.

Comment: I resolved the issue, thank you for considering. Was writing the *tan* improperly causing imparement on viewer screens? Or was it just the proper-perfectionist way of using MathJax?

Comment: It makes you look less of an amateur.

Comment: @Shaun Ahh. Thank you, in that case

Comment: Also, use, for example, `$x^2$` for $x^2$. In fact: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Comment: One last thing: what if I'm running low on characters left? Isn't it appropriate to save some spaces by using θ instead of \theta?

Comment: Well . . . *sometimes*, like in a tilte. I have used `$θ$` for $\theta$ recently in fact.

Comment: Generally speaking, though, it is frowned upon.

Comment: @Shaun I believe then it must be some what of a last-resort type of option. I thank you, once again, for this knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

We assume that $B$ and $C$ are on the $x$-axis (as opposed to the $y$-axis), and that $B$ is on the right of $C$.

We further assume that point $A$ is in the first quadrant. So $\angle{B}-\angle{C}=a$.

[image]

For convenience, I will write $B$ instead of $\angle{B}$, and $C$ instead of $\angle{C}$.

$$\tan{B}=\frac{y}{a-x}$$

$$\tan{C}=\frac{y}{a+x}$$

$$\tan{(B-C)}=\tan{a}$$

$$\implies \frac{\frac{y}{a-x}-\frac{y}{a+x}}{1+(\frac{y}{a-x})(\frac{y}{a+x})}=\tan{a}$$

$$\implies x^2-y^2+\frac{2}{\tan{a}}xy-a^2=0 \text{ with } x>0 \text{ and } y>0$$

[image]

Alternatively, we could have assumed that point $A$ is in any of the other three quadrants. Accordingly, we reflect the curve in the $x$-axis and $y$-axis. That is, we add absolute value signs around every $x$ and $y$, but note that they don't make a difference in $x^2$ and $y^2$.

So our final solution is

$$x^2-y^2+\frac{2}{\tan{a}}|xy|-a^2=0$$

[image]

Comment: +1. Geometrically, the curves are (portions of) rectangular hyperbolas whose transverse axes make an angle of $45^\circ-\frac12\alpha$ with the $x$-axis.